# Unable to install / blank screen

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

Been trying to install 5.1 on dual boot with windows 10.
Created a bootable usb and it goes on right onto try or install elementary OS. I press enter and then nothing - screen stays black / blank forever. Help please. Need to run away from windows.

Running intel core i3 with 128g ssd 8gb ram and Intel uhd 625 graphics.

Comment: Do you have a dual GPU (intel and nvidia)? Or just intelHD onboard? if you have nVidia, **[please check my answer here in that case](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/blank-screen-after-try-elementary-button-clicked/21929#21929)**

Comment: just built in Intel UHD 625.its a laptop ps

Comment: Can you try adding i915.modeset=0 to the kernel boot line (again, you can refer the post I linked above on how)

Comment: PS that didn't work. (I915.nomodeset=0) However tried enabling secure boot and fast boot - which worked! Would love to know the science behind it however :)