# Can't boot from USB, hangs on system load

Tags: boot

I have set up a USB with eOS using Rufus and everything goes smoothly up to the point where the OS loads from USB. It hangs after ~7s during system load, with last driver/module load log on screen (last logs are from USB devices and audio)

Tried different Rufus settings, tried BalenaEtcher as well, same thing. Tried acpi=off as well. Read about the MCE issue with Zen 2 so I used mce=off too, nothing changed. If it helps, Mint also doesn't boot. I suspect it's a hardware issue, as I have a fairly new system:

AMD Threadripper 3960X, 
G.SKILL 4x 16GB DDR4 3600MHz, 
2x Sabrent PCI-E 4.0 2TB NVMe drive, 
Seagate Barracuda Pro 12TB, 
EVGA GeForce RTX 2080Ti

Newest eOS downloaded today (5.1.2 20200204).

Comment: Can you try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/blank-screen-after-try-elementary-button-clicked/21929#21929 ?

Comment: It did throw a bunch of critical looking errors about BIOS so I thought it's no use, but after 10s or so it booted!
I was able to install OS just fine and did upgrade the kernel afterwards to 5.5.9 to fix the MCE issue, but during boot I can still see the BIOS errors (system works fine though).
The only thing doesn't working is sound and sound settings - settings app crashes when I open sound settings.